# Delphi detect arrow key in form

Tags: delphi, events, key

I have a Delphi VCL form with many frames containing components. I want to detect an arrow key click in a the form so that I can move between frames that are graphically arranged in a matrix. Both Keypress and Keydown event handlers fail to respond to an arrow key press.  I have created case elements for virtual keys in both methods but the event is not triggered by the arrow keys. How is this accomplished in Delphi?

Comment: Thanks, The duplicate didn't show up when I asked the question. but appears to work.

Answer (score 4):

Arrow keys are reserved by the OS for navigation purposes.  UI controls do not receive window messages for arrow key presses unless they explicitly request it. You need to either:

- handle the Win32 [`WM_GETDLGCODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-getdlgcode) message and include the `DLGC_WANTARROWS` flag in its return value.
- handle the VCL's custom `CM_DIALOGKEY` message.
- use a keyboard hook via the Win32 [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) function.